# Can I change or upload a file in the directory of my html-file?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have the following situation:
There is an HTML file in some directory on my PC. If I open this HTML file in a browser, I want to click a button with which I can write or change a file in the same directory.

So there is no server whatsoever, just an HTML file opened in a browser.
Is this possible?
Calling a **python script** from a button would also work for me.

I just have to be able to detect a change in the directory when the button is clicked.

Comment: No, you need a server. The server can also run locally. Since you seem to be familiar with Python, maybe you want to look into Django.

Comment: no it is not possible without server.

Comment: Not even something like writing a log? Like replace console.log() with something? Or even change the html file itself, anything would work that would change something in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

Yes it is. but there is additional system like `git`. and you need to implement using `javascript`.

#### Not a solution

I am sorry about I can not provide exact solution about your question. but I can give you keywords. I assume you do not know about `git`.

I recommend implement local `git` system for your local directory. because  there is lot of changes your files. (like edit single character or add new files) and some of files you do not want detected (that's mentioned in `.gitignore`)

and there is suitable project for you [isomorphic-git](https://github.com/isomorphic-git/isomorphic-git)
. and If you heard about `git` first, also check [github guide](https://guides.github.com).